# Migrating application context configuration to Spring 3.1 and Hibernate 4.0

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, migration

I'm having hard time finding migration docs. I was using sping 3.0.5 and hibernate 3.4.

I migrated to the latest release candidates: spring 3.1 and hibernate 4.0

I was able to refactor my classes without problem but the application context for hibernate is giving me problems since I have not see any examples on how to configure it.

Specifically:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>...</list>
   </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
          ... 
          <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
          <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">????</prop>
          ...
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Apparently properties `dataSource` , `mappingResources` and `hibernateProperties` no longer exist and I'm not so sure about what to put in `hibernate.connection.provider_class` and `hibernate.cache.provider_class`.

And I keep getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition
```

at application start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, Spring has no support for Hibernate 4. If it did, I'd expect to see an `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4` package in the [3.1.x package list](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/), but it's not there. I don't believe I've seen any mention of it in any release notes or anything, either.

In other words, Spring is working fine, but you're using an incompatible version of Hibernate.

Comment: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8096?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3achangehistory-tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

`dataSource` still exists, based on the [JavaDoc for LocalSessionFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html).  See the section at the very top; it has an example config with a `dataSource` property.  `mappingResources` also exists.

The [Spring 3.1 reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) also has an example, with `dataSource` and `mappingResources`.

Hibernate 4 does not have a ref guide yet.